# Overriding twitter bootstrap in less, twice

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have an app with two styles in it. Both styles were developed independently, and then merged into a single less file. Both styles use twitter bootstrap, overriding it by using custom variables.less files. Currently, it looks like this:

```
.outer { @import "bootstrap.less"; @import "outer-variables.less"; @import "more-outer.less" }
.inner { @import "bootstrap.less"; @import "inner-variables.less"; @import "more-inner.less" }
```

Inner/outer use different fonts, colors, margins, etc, all customized in variables.less. They also use lots of other rules, of course.

This works just fine, but results in 2 full copies of compiled bootstrap in my CSS. Seeing as CSS and Less are cascading, I thought there would be some way to get the same effect, but only including bootstrap.less once. However, I can't get it to work. Anyone know how?

Here's what I tried:

```
@import "bootstrap.less"; // doesn't compile, missing vars
.outer { @import "outer-variables.less"; @import "more-outer.less" }
.inner { @import "inner-variables.less"; @import "more-inner.less" }
```

And:

```
@import "bootstrap.less";
@import "outer-variables.less"; 
@import "inner-variables.less"; // ends up using inner styles everywhere
.outer { @import "outer-variables.less"; @import "more-outer.less" }
.inner { @import "inner-variables.less"; @import "more-inner.less" }
```

Neither work. What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would think the `@import-once` (which is actually the default in LESS 1.4 for `@import`, but not in previous versions) should help you. Maybe something like:

### Idea #1

```
.outer { 
 @import-once "bootstrap.less"; 
 @import "outer-variables.less"; 
 @import "more-outer.less" 
}
.inner { 
 @import-once "bootstrap.less"; 
 @import "inner-variables.less"; 
 @import "more-inner.less" 
}
```

That *should* work to not re-import the whole bootstrap framework, however, because you are nesting it inside selectors, I could be wrong about that. I have not specifically tested this.

If that does not work, then maybe...

### Idea #2

```
 @import "bootstrap.less"; 
 @import "outer-variables.less"; /* give bootstrap some initial variables */    
.outer { 
 @import "more-outer.less" /* use initial variables */
}
.inner { 
 @import "inner-variables.less"; /* override initial variables inside inner */
 @import "more-inner.less" /* use override variables */
}
```